# Enum datatype in interface in C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

How to use enum datatype in interface?

Is this possible?

```
public interface IParent1
{
    string method1(Test enum);
}

public class Parent1 : IParent1
{
    public enum Test 
    {
        A, 
        B, 
        C
    }

    public string method1(Test enum)
    {
        return enum.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried? (it's not possible to use keywords as identifiers though, (unless they are prefixed with '@')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`enum` is a reserved keyword in C#. You can prefix it with `@` if you want to use it as variable name:

```
public enum Test { A, B, C };

public interface IParent1
{
    string method1(Test @enum);
}

public class Parent1 : IParent1
{
    public string method1(Test @enum)
    {
        return @enum.ToString();
    }
}
```

But I don't like using reserved words for variable names. A better approach would be:

```
public enum Test { A, B, C };

public interface IParent1
{
    string method1(Test test);
}

public class Parent1 : IParent1
{
    public string method1(Test test)
    {
        return test.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, for clarity and readability, change the name of the argument to something that is not a reserved word in C# (or preferably in any .NET language in general).

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any problem with that. But why do you nest your enum declaration in the interface implementation? Your code will not compile, because:
1. You're using reserved word `enum`
2. `value` is not declared

Try use this:

```
public enum Test { A, B, C };

public interface IParent1 { string method1(Test @enum);}

public class Parent1 : IParent1
{
    public string method1(Test @enum)
    {
        return @enum.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your enum to be different in each implementing class you should use a generic interface like

```
public interface MyInterface<T>
{
    string MyMethod(T myEnum)
}
```

If it should be the same for all implementing classes just don't put it outside any class:

```
public enum MyEnum { A, B, C }

public interface MyInterface
{
    string MyMethod(MyEnum myEnum)
}
```